# Passing the value through AJAX showing 200 error

Tags: php, ajax

```
dataString = { question: CKEDITOR.instances.question.getData(), option1: CKEDITOR.instances.option1.getData() };
    var jsonString = JSON.stringify(dataString);
    
$.ajax({
    url: "include/process1.php",// your request url
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "json",
    data: {data :jsonString},
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Using JSON.stringify to pass an array data through ajax to my other page but it is showing 200 error and not returning any data data.
The situation is that i have used 4 CKEDITOR to get input from as i need mathematical equations.
But when using getting this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMhPS.png)

Comment: Http *"error"* code 200 is *"OK"* (no error)

Comment: Where did you get "error" from? The screen dump just shows a successful request. What is your actual issue? What doesn't work as expected? I would rather question why you pass the data as a json string instead of just posting the json object "as is"?

Comment: 200 response is not error

Answer (score 0):

Status 200 OK is not an error but it is a success response. Are you sending any data as a response from php? (You can echo data in php as a response)

Comment: Yes i have sent data from php code as response but when i try to alert that data it shows nothing

Comment: If you don't mind, can you please show me your php code?